# Close multiple folders at once

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this part of code into a vb.net project to close three specific folders but only two of them close. Any idea why is this happening?

```
Private Sub CloseFolders_Button_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles CloseFolders_Button.MouseClick
    Dim FrapsFolder_C As String = FrapsFolder_TextBox.Text
    Dim DestVideoFolder_C As String = DestVideoFolder_TextBox.Text
    Dim DestImagesFolder_C As String = DestImagesFolder_TextBox.Text
    Dim sh As Object = CreateObject("shell.application")

    For Each w In sh.Windows
        If w.document.folder.self.Path = FrapsFolder_C Or
            w.document.folder.self.Path = DestVideoFolder_C Or
            w.document.folder.self.Path = DestImagesFolder_C Then
            w.Quit
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It is a troublesome api, this dates back to the days when they tried to make Explorer similar to a browser.  Do favor the w.URL property, you just have to filter out the file:// prefix.  And keep in mind that Explorer is a single-instance app, when you start it 3 times then you still only have 1 process that displays the 3 windows.  Keep an eye on Task Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very weird problem. I waste plenty of time trying to solve with no outcome. However, I did my best to solve the issue with playing around it.

I just re-wrote your main code into a sub-routine to be able to use it several times according to number of open folders.

```
Sub CloseFolders(folder1 As String, folder2 As String, folder3 As String)
    Try
        For Each w In sh.windows
          ' I used select .. case instead of if statement for readability 
            Select Case w.document.folder.self.Path
                Case folder1, folder2, folder3
                    w.Quit()
            End Select
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then in click event you can call this sub-routine, like this:

```
    For i As Integer = sh.windows.count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        CloseFolders(FrapsFolder_TextBox.Text, DestVideoFolder_TextBox.Text, DestImagesFolder_TextBox.Text)
    Next
```

Do not forget to declare and create shell

```
Dim sh As Object = CreateObject("shell.application")
```

I am looking forward to find better solution. I think to use process instead of shell, I'm not sure it will work either, but I preferred to be close to your original code as much as I could.

Comment: My friend Abdulfattah, it worked once (!!!), but then, as many times as I tried to close the folders, I have the same problem. If you know any other way as you said, please show me. There is no problem to make it work using an other way!!!

Comment: I also get this error... `Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)`

Comment: @Simonetos 

What do you mean by worked "once"? It works fine for me. Please make sure that you declare shell once and above all subs.

Look at this screenshot, please
http://imgur.com/a/UdNPo

for the error message it is not avoidable with this method. You can hide it with removing the messageBox statement from Catch; i.e leave it empty.

Comment: Have you put the code inside "try block" as I did in the screenshot above. If so, there is no way for getting application error :)

Comment: Anyway, try to close the open folders using "kill process" method; it could work for you.

Comment: I had declare `sh` variable once and above all subs and I had hide the messagebox statement from Catch before you comment, but I was still getting this error `Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)` as application error!!!

Anyway, your code is working perfect now!!! The problem were on the way I was opening-loading those three folders. After I added some delay from `Procces.Start` to `Procces.Start` everything is OK. Thank you very much my friend!!!